# Drawing rounded/movable area over image

Tags: reactjs, math, svg, quadratic-curve

I would like to draw rounded area and points over a photo.
I decided to do it with a svg which is simplier to make it resizable and movable.

But, from a list of points I do not have an area which go through all points.
I used the Quadratic Bezier CurveTo, but I am not able to find the mathematic formula to give the the "Q parameter" the values to calculate the control point to go from A to C passing by B.
For the moment, when the angle is too high, the line "turn" before the point, but i would like to go touch the point.

[image][image]

Comment: So the bottom picture is what you want?

Comment: Yes that's it :)

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/1089719

Comment: More specifically: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spline_interpolation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is infinite number of curves through point B.

Let define that `B` lies on the curve at parameter `t=1/2`

Quadratic curve with unknown control point `Q` has equation

```
P(t) = A*(1-t)^2 + 2*Q*t*(1-t) + C*t^2
```

Substiting point `B` and `t=1/2`, we have

```
B = A/4 + Q/2 + C/4

Q = 2*B - A/2 - C/2
or in coordinates
Q.x = 2*B.x - A.x/2 - C.x/2
Q.y = 2*B.y - A.y/2 - C.y/2
```

This very simple method should work well when `B` is near symmetrical relative to `A` and `C`

```
Q.x = 2*7 - 0 - 20/2 = 4
Q.y = 2*10 - 0 - 0 = 20
```

[image]

Comment: I will try this 
Thanks for this detailed response :)